# Messy code when I open a lua file contain Chinese with MacVim

Tags: macvim

How to set MacVim display code.

Here is the mess when I open the lua file which create in Windows XP.

gControlMode = 0;  -- 1£º¿ªÆôÖØÁ¦¸ÐÓ¦£¬ 0:¿ª´¥ÆÁÄ£Ê½

gState = GS_GAME;

sTotalTime = 0;   --µ±Ç°¹Ø¿¨»¨µÄ×ÜÊ±¼ä

Answer (score 0):

The text you posted seems like a Latin-1 (or ISO-8859-1, CP819) decoding of the CP936 encoding (or EUC‑CN, or GB18030 encodings<sup>1</sup>) of this text<sup>2</sup>:

```
gControlMode = 0; -- 1：开启重力感应， 0:开触屏模式

gState = GS_GAME;

sTotalTime = 0; --当前关卡花的总时间
```

When opening a file, Vim tries the list of encodings specified in the [`fileencodings` option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27fileencodings%27). Usually, `latin1` is the last value in this list; reading as Latin-1 will always be successful since it is an 8-bit encoding that maps all 256 values. Thus, Vim is opening your CP936 encoded file as Latin-1.

You have several choices for getting Vim to use another encoding:

- You can specify an encoding with the [`++enc=` option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%2B%2Benc) to Vim’s `:edit` command (this will cause Vim to ignore the `fileencodings` list for the buffer):

  ```
  :e ++enc=cp936 /path/to/file
  ```

  You can apply this to an already-loaded file by leaving off the path:

  ```
  :e ++enc=cp936
  ```
- You can add your preferred encoding to `fileencodings` just before `latin1` (e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`):

  ```
  let &fileencodings = substitute(&fileencodings, 'latin1', 'cp936,\0', '')
  ```
- You can set the `encoding` option to your desired encoding. This is usually discouraged because it has wide-ranging impacts (see [`:help encoding`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27encoding%27)).

---

It might make sense, if possible, to switch your files to UTF-8 since many editors will properly auto-detect UTF-8. Once you have the file loaded properly (see above), Vim can do the conversion like this (set `fileencoding`, then `:write`):

```
:set fenc=utf-8 | w
```

Vim should pretty much automatically handle reading and writing UTF-8 files (`encoding` defaults to UTF-8, and `utf-8` is in the default `fileencodings`), but if you are using other editors (i.e. whatever Windows editor edited/created the CP936 file(s)), you may need to configure them to use UTF-8 instead of (e.g.) CP936.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am not familiar with the encodings used for Chinese text, these encodings seem to be identical for the “expected” text.
<sup>2</sup> I do not read Chinese, but the presence and locations of the FULLWIDTH COLON and FULLWIDTH COMMA (and Google's translation of this text) make me think this is the text you expected.